# How to support dash dateformat in mat-datepicker using angular 4/5 with reactive forms

Tags: angular-material, angular4-forms

I am trying to customized date-format. I am trying to render [mm-dd-yyyy] date format but its not supporting

new Date() with angular 4 new form control not accepting this date format.

But when we pass it will console.log invalid date.

Answer (score 1):

Angular Material uses moment.js to custmize date format, as it's explained [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings)

So to make it work try the following:

```
...
import {MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS, MomentDateAdapter} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';

// Depending on whether rollup is used, moment needs to be imported differently.
// Since Moment.js doesn't have a default export, we normally need to import using the `* as`
// syntax. However, rollup creates a synthetic default module and we thus need to import it using
// the `default as` syntax.
import * as _moment from 'moment';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
import {default as _rollupMoment} from 'moment';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

/** @title Datepicker that uses Moment.js dates */
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [
    // `MomentDateAdapter` and `MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS` can be automatically provided by importing
    // `MatMomentDateModule` in your applications root module. We provide it at the component level
    // here, due to limitations of our example generation script.
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerMomentExample {
  // Datepicker takes `Moment` objects instead of `Date` objects.
  date = new FormControl(moment([2017, 0, 1]));
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qxqoqexmqvl)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the best library for managing dates: https://momentjs.com/

If you look in the documentation you will surely find out how to perform the validation you are looking for.

Otherwise post the code you are trying